# Suffix tree vs Suffix array for LCS

Tags: c++, algorithm, suffix-tree, suffix-array

I'm working on a program to find the longest common substring between multiple strings. I've lowered my approach down to either using suffix array's or a suffix tree. I want to see which is the better approach (if there is one) and why. Also for suffix array's I've seen a few algorithms for two strings but not any for more then two strings. Any solid examples would be appreciated, thanks again for the advice!

Note: I didn't see any other questions that specifically addressed this issue, but if they exist please point me in that direction!

Comment: So what is the ultimate goal? Finding the pair which has the longest common substring? (I.e. finding the two most "similar" strings in the sense of common substring)

Comment: I note that the LCS problem for _multiple_ strings is significantly harder than for two strings. The first sentence of the main complexity section at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_subsequence_problem states that it is NP-hard. The first implementation that I could find, http://search.cpan.org/~vmoiseev/Algorithm-MLCS-1.0/lib/Algorithm/MLCS.pm is a heuristic implementation that does not guarantee to find the absolute best solution.

Comment: Oops - ignore last comment. I confused longest common subsequence and longest common substring - sorry.

Comment: @leemes The goal is to find the exact common substring between multiple strings of DNA. I'm not sure exactly how many substrings it will be until I get my results back, but I'm guessing as few as 4 and as many as 7 or 8 (probably closer to the lower end).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a substring that occurs in all sequences, then in a suffix array, the pointers to each occurrence of that substring must sort close together. So you could attempt to find them by moving a window along the suffix array, where the window is just large enough to contain at least one occurrence of each sequence. You could do this in linear time by maintaining a table that tells you, for each sequence, how many times that sequence occurs within that window. Then when you move the rear end of the window forwards decrement the count for the sequence associated with the pointer you have just skipped over and, if necessary, move the forward end of the window just far enough to pick up a new occurrence of this sequence and update the table.

Now you need to be able to find the length of the common prefix shared by all substrings starting at the pointers in the window. This should be the minimum LCP value occurring between the pointers in the window. If you use a red-black tree, such as a Java Treeset, with a key which consists of the LCP value as most significant component and some tie-breaker such as the pointer itself as a less significant component, then you can maintain the minimum LCP value within the window at a cost of roughly log window size per window adjustment.

Comment: When you find a few substrings in your window, how can you be sure each of them is from a different source string? They could be repetitions of a certain substring within one and the same source string, no?

Comment: I am assuming that there is some sort of marker carried with the pointers. For instance, if you create the suffix array by concatenating all of the input strings, you can keep track of what ranges of index correspond with which input string and then tell from the index at which a substring starts which input string it is from. At the beginning, and every time you move the rear window position forwards, you can use these checks to make sure the front window position is far enough forwards that it includes at least one pointer from each input string.

Comment: Yes, but in that case, how can you define the size of the window? It's no longer bounded by the number of source strings.

Comment: As the rear position of the window moves, its front position must move just far enough so that it contains one of each sort of input string. For some choices of input data - for instance if the answer is the empty string - the window will be almost the entire suffix array, but the cost of updating the data structures needed to work out where the window ends and what the minimum LCP value is is still manageable - about the log of the window size.

Comment: Ok. I just think it's important to be aware that this red-black tree will grow extremely large in some cases.